# Issue with delete action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with my delete action and link. Here is my link :

```
<%= link_to 'Supprimer la thématique', @theme, method: :delete, data: { confirm:'Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer la thématique' }, :class => "btn btn-default" %>
```

And I don't know why, but this link redirect to the show action of my model 'theme'.

I can resolve this by using `button_to` but with a `button_to` I'm not able to set a data confirm :

```
<%= button_to "Supprimer la thématique", @theme, :method=>:delete, data: { confirm: 'Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer la thématique ?'}, :class=> 'btn btn-default' %>
```

Do you have any ideas why the link to doesn't redirect to the delete action or why I can't have a data confirm for my `button_to` ?

Comment: Can you show us what is in @theme variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking a link always sends a GET request, unless there's Javascript in place that does something different, such as sending an Ajax request or submitting a hidden form. When using regular resourceful routes, the `show` action and `destroy` action share a route, and determine what to do based on the method (as you probably know).

The `button_to` method should support a confirmation dialog; if it doesn't work, then there's probably some Javascript missing.

Both your problems point to a missing unobtrusive Javascript driver. If using jquery-rails (the standard option), make sure that it's listed in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

and that you're loading it in your application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Also be sure that you're calling the `javascript_include_tag` method in your application layout. Once you've got jquery-rails loaded properly, you should be able to get the results you're looking for with either method you've attempted.

For more information on loading jquery-rails, see [the Github repo](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs#installation-using-the-jquery-rails-gem).